# How do i get point coordinates after object modified?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I would like to get the new point coordinates after object being modified but when i get the points coordinates after being modified they are the same point coordinates with which I have drawn the polygon.
Can anyone please tell me why it so? Below is my code,

```
<!--fabricjs -->
canvas.on('object:modified', function(e){

 var obj=e.target;
 console.log("new point coordinates "+obj.points);
});
```

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Fidel90 yes I got it but with ROTATE option being disabled. Subtract each point with pathOffset and then multiply each point with Tranform matrix. This works without ROTATE.

Comment: Here's an example with ROTATE transformation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53710375/4681279

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code I used to get the updated points with ROTATE being disabled.
But if I get the updated points using below code with rotate option being enabled and after rotating the object, I get wrong set of points , so for now I have disabled the rotate option. It will be great help if any one could say how can I modify below code to have the rotate option enabled and get right set of points.

```
<!-- fabric js -->
        canvas.on('object:modified', function(e) {
                var newCoordinates = "";
                var matrix = [];
                var polygon = canvas.getItemById(e.target.id);
                matrix = polygon.calcTransformMatrix();
                var translatedPoints = polygon.get('points').map(function(p) {
                    return {
                        x: p.x - polygon.pathOffset.x,
                        y: p.y - polygon.pathOffset.y
                    };
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < translatedPoints.length; i++) {
                    translatedPoints[i].x = matrix[0] * translatedPoints[i].x + matrix[2] * translatedPoints[i].y + matrix[4];
                    translatedPoints[i].y = matrix[1] * translatedPoints[i].x + matrix[3] * translatedPoints[i].y + matrix[5];
                }
                var newUpdatedPoints = JSON.stringify(translatedPoints);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies here:

```
translatedPoints[i].x = matrix[0] * translatedPoints[i].x + matrix[2] * translatedPoints[i].y + matrix[4];

translatedPoints[i].y = matrix[1] * translatedPoints[i].x + matrix[3] * translatedPoints[i].y + matrix[5];
```

You're transforming the point y based on the transformed point x. This should work:

```
translatedPoints[i] = new fabric.Point(
    matrix[0] * translatedPoints[i].x + matrix[2] * translatedPoints[i].y + matrix[4],
    matrix[1] * translatedPoints[i].x + matrix[3] * translatedPoints[i].y + matrix[5]
)
```

Anyway I think it's better using fabric.js own transform function rather than trying to implement it.

```
translatedPoints[i] = fabric.util.transformPoint(
    translatedPoints[i],
    matrix
)
```

In [this article](https://medium.com/@luizzappa/how-to-find-out-the-coordinates-of-vertices-of-a-shape-in-fabric-js-a871109085c1) there is more detail on the logic behind these transformations. *Disclosure*: I'm the author of this article.